# I forgot the Password for WPA/WPA2 Personal where can I get it

Tags: macos, wifi, password

I'am trying to set up a wireless connection to my HP OfficeJet printer. For this I need to enter the password to my WLAN which I forgot.

How and where can I retrieve it?

Comment: Did you look in your system and log in keychain?

Comment: Do you have access to your router's admin interface? Typically at `192.168.1.1`

Answer (score 8):

1. Open the **Keychain Access** app (located in the **Utilities** folder, within the **Applications** folder).
2. In the search box (upper right corner), type in the name of your Wi-Fi network.
3. Double click the corresponding entry in the main panel. If there is more than one, look for the most recent one with a type matching "AirPort network password".
4. Click the checkbox labelled *Show password*, and enter your user account password when prompted. The password will be displayed in the text box, where you can copy it as needed.

[image]

Comment: If it's not stored in the keychain, you will be out of luck unless you recall somewhere else you stored that information on your Mac.

Comment: Many (but certainly not all) routers store the password in plaintext in their web interface. But of course this requires knowing the password to that…

Answer (score 1):

If you have Cydia on your iPhone, iPod or iPad you can download "**WiFi Passwords**" from Xsellize repo. Its free and it will show you all your stored WiFi networks you've been connected to along with their associated passwords.

Is not hacking, is just reading the stored information stored in your iPhone, iPod or iPad.

Comment: The question is about OS X not for iOS.

Comment: @maseth It's still a good answer since anywhere the password is recorded will help the asker - especially if it's not in the keychain. Of course, that's a more likely answer, but I bet this helps someone at some point.

Answer (score 1):

As a last resort, you can reset your WLAN to factory settings and put in a new password of your choice...

Comment: In a sense, the router maintains the password for the WLAN and all the other answers are similar to looking for the password written on a yellow sticky note.

Answer (score -1):

take a backup of the router config file and use nirsoft tools to view the config file in order to get the password in text format.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions